# Recursive directory listing in Windows with negated wildcards

Tags: windows, command-line

Using the Windows command prompt, how can I recursively list filenames **not** containing "cat"?
For example, I have these files:

```
C:\big cat.jpg
C:\Dir1\big dog.jpg
C:\Dir1\big cat.jpg
C:\No cats here\my dog.jpg
```

I want to run a command which will produce:

```
C:\Dir1\big dog.jpg
C:\No cats here\my dog.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

`dir | findstr /i /l /v "cat"` should do it.

This will pipe the directory listing to `findstr` and output lines that don’t contain `cat`. It will use the string `cat` literally instead of as a regex expression and ignore case.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr

Comment: Thanks! That gives me a good start.
I used
dir /a:-d /b /s | findstr /l /v "cat"
to search recursively and exclude directories but it doesn't list
C:\No cats here\my dog.jpg
I'll have to work out a regular expression for findstr to accept "cat" in folder names but not in the file name.